# FFmpeg not copying all audio streams

Tags: linux, windows, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm having trouble getting ffmpeg to copy all audio streams from a .mp4 file. After hours of searching online, it appears this should copy *all* streams ([as shown in example 4 here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map#Example4)):

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -map 0 -c copy out.mp4
```

`in.mp4` contains 3 streams:

- Video
- Audio track 1
- Audio track 2

`out.mp4` (which should be identical to `in.mp4`) contains only 2 streams:

- Video
- Audio track 1

FFmpeg does appear to correctly identify all 3 streams, but doesn't copy all of them over. Output from FFmpeg:

```
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
  Stream #0:2 -> #0:2 (copy)
```

**Edit:** Output from `ffmpeg -v 9 -loglevel 99 -i in.mp4`:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from in.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.36.100
  Duration: 00:00:06.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 5582 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und), 1, 1/15360: Video: h264 (Main), 1 reference frame (avc1 /
0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg/unknown/unknown, left), 1920x1080 (0x0) [SAR 1:
1 DAR 16:9], 0/1, 5317 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und), 1, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz,
 stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
    Stream #0:2(und), 1, 1/48000: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz,
 stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Successfully opened the file.
At least one output file must be specified
[AVIOContext @ 0000000001c2b9e0] Statistics: 153350 bytes read, 2 seeks
```

**Edit 2 (solved):** I managed to find the correct syntax from [this ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1056). For any others that are interested, the correct syntax is:

`ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0 out.mp4`

This will copy all streams.

Comment: Which version of ffmpeg are you using, on what platform? The output of `ffmpeg -v 9 -loglevel 99 -i in.mp4` would be helpful, according to the "Bug Reports" page on  https://ffmpeg.org/bugreports.html.

Comment: I've added the output from `ffmpeg -v 9 -loglevel 99 -i`. Platform is Windows. FFmpeg version is `git-0a9e781 (2016-06-10)`.

Comment: Relevant doc: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map#Example4

Comment: `-map 0` copies the audio but not correctly: no sound is heard when the MP4 file is played. On the other hand `-map 1`  works perfctly. Yet, I upvoted you --some guys in here would downvote you!-- because you helped me find a solution to a pain!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently this is a popular question, so I'm posting my solution as an answer (was previously a comment reply) so that others can see.

I managed to find the correct syntax from this [ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1056). The correct syntax is:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 out.mp4
```

This will copy all 3 streams.

Comment: I give +1 for answer, but it would be very helpful to amend it with: To select all video and the third audio stream from an input file: ffmpeg -i INPUT -map 0:v -map 0:a:2 OUTPUT Same is fo all audio streams, which could be noted as 0:a

Answer (score 61):

FFmpeg have option to map all streams to output, you have to use option `-map 0` to map all streams from input to output.

In full line it might look like:

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -c copy -map 0 out.mp4
```

For more info see the documentation on [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) and the [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) option.

Comment: This was super helpful. You interested in adding a full command to make it easier?
`ffmpeg -i IN.mp4 -c copy -map 0:? OUT.mp4`

Comment: For multiple sources like `-i in0.mp4 -i in1.aac` one need to add `-map 0 -map 1` to mux all input streams.

Comment: You can replace `-map 0:?` with just `-map 0`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but ignore subs? I am trying to -ss clip videos and if the subs are not certain format, they throw errors. Ideally I would like to just convert subs to a usable format and preserve them.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I read pretty deep into the `ffmpeg` man page and found this which should be useful:

> Note that currently each output stream can only contain channels from
>   a single input stream; you can't for example use "-map_channel" to
>   pick multiple input audio channels contained in different streams
>   (from the same or different files) and merge them into a single output
>   stream. It is therefore not currently possible, for example, to turn
>   two separate mono streams into a single stereo stream. However
>   splitting a stereo stream into two single channel mono streams is
>   possible.
>
> If you need this feature, a possible workaround is to use the amerge
>   filter. For example, if you need to merge a media (here input.mkv)
>   with 2 mono audio streams into one single stereo channel audio stream
>   (and keep the video stream), you can use the following command:

`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter_complex "[0:1] [0:2] amerge" -c:a pcm_s16le -c:v copy output.mkv`

You may want to read through and experiment with the man page instructions on `man ffmpeg-filters` to understand just what level of complexity you're getting into for naming channels and expected output.

[Edit: As Mulvya noted, this answers a question, but it was not quite the original poster's question.]

Comment: Excellent, I'll do some experimenting. Thanks.

Comment: I managed to find the correct syntax from [this ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1056). For any others that are interested, the correct syntax is: `ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec copy -c:a copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 out.mp4`, this will copy all 3 streams.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the OP's query. They want to copy tracks over, not merge or split them. The OP's original command should work, as the `stream mapping` code shows. It is a mystery why it doesn't but the separate stream codec syntax does. Can the OP share the console output for the original copy command?

Answer (score 1):

First I tried this broader answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54616353/1422630

But I had trouble with a not supported subtitle track so I ended having to use this command:

`avconv -i INFILE -c copy -map 0:a -map 0:v OUTFILE`

I understand that, after I asked to copy, it basically copied **only what I mapped** (and it mapped all audio of course), as I don't care for the subtitles being embedded at all. If you want to map the subtitles, just add this `-map 0:s`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that specific ffmpeg versions ignore `-c copy` option and skip audio stream copy, thus resulting in final file with no audio, e.g. does not copy audio tracks and produce video with no sound.

The ffmpeg affected is for example used on Synology Disk Station devices:

```
ffmpeg version 2.7.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG 1.20.0) 20150311 (prerelease)
```

To resolve that, without analyzing file structure and manually mapping all audio streams with -map 0:1 -map 0:2 etc, I found very simple command to process it automatically:

```
ffmpeg -i INFILE -map 0 -c copy -c:a copy OUTFILE
```

This is different from `-c:v -c:a` as preserves chapters and subtitles together with video and all audio tracks with different languages, like english, spanish, french, russian or chineese.

Also in case you have more hardly broken file, which simple copy does not fix, please try this command, which potentially fix more errors, which could crash video player, or stuck video or audio:

```
ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -i INFILE -map 0 -c copy -c:a copy OUTFILE
```